# Identify unique subjects by year using PROC SQL in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have a healthcare dataset each subject visit getting an observation.  I'd like to know how many unique subjects there are per year.  I.e. unique-identifier is "SSN" and the year variable = "FY".  I know how to get just a count of unique individuals:

proc SQL;
select count(distinct SSN) as distinct_ssns
from work.myfile;
quit;

Is there a way to just group by FY?  So I would just get unique SSN's per FY?

Thanks so much!
Ben

Comment: Please include table definition to give us a chance to help you without guessing, like were do we get the year from?

Answer (score 1):

Add FY to the SELECT and GROUP BY

```
proc SQL;
select fy, count(distinct SSN) as distinct_ssns 
from work.myfile 
group by fy; 
quit;
```